# Calculation of CO2 mass in 330mls can coke

Tags: physical-chemistry, food-chemistry

How can I Calculate mass of CO2 in a 330 ml's of can coke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9067/what-is-the-carbon-dioxide-content-of-a-soda-can-or-bottle), it seems that there's a little over 2g of carbon dioxide in a can of Coke.

Do you mean 'calculate', or 'measure'?

If you mean 'measure', many electronic balances will weigh to this sort of precision, so you could just weigh the can before opening, then let it go flat, then weigh it again.

To calculate it, you'd need to know how whether they saturate the solution, what the can pressure is, and the solubility of carbon dioxide in Coke at that pressure.  This may be significantly different from the solubility in water at the same pressure, and not easy to find out, since the Coke recipe is secret.

Comment: The coke recipe is not exactly a secret. I takes a reasonably well-equipped laboratory half a day to find out *exactly* what's in there, and be assured that Pepsi and all other competitors have done  that, and probably do it as a weekly routine. ;-)