# Why does it hurt in the mouth when drinking carbonated beverages?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, colloids

The typical explanation for the origin of the "sting" is that $\ce{CO2}$ turns into carbonic acid ([reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/3mx5jk/why_does_the_fizz_in_carbonated_drinks_hurt_my/), [yahoo](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=1006050228925)), however the "explanations" there are   incomplete.

The answer I'm looking for would cover:

1. Is conversion to carbonic acid is really the case here? And what are the original compounds the same enzyme(s) is used for?
2. Why is there no "sting" from $\ce{CO2}$ found in air?

Comment: http://articles.latimes.com/2013/aug/22/science/la-sci-sn-the-soda-bite-not-bubbles-20130821

Comment: "The earliest clues that carbonic acid, not bubbles, were responsible for this sensation came from mountaineers’ accounts of the “champagne blues.” After pouring a bottle of celebratory champagne at the summit, mountaineers who had taken medication for altitude sickness disappointedly remarked on the drink’s flat taste — despite its fizziness. It turns out the medication blocked the enzyme that converts carbon dioxide into carbonic acid."

Comment: @QuantumAMERICCINO thanks. They don't mention why this is not happening with air.

Comment: Hmm interesting. According to https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9067/what-is-the-carbon-dioxide-content-of-a-soda-can-or-bottle

, a can has 2.2 g of CO2 in a 355 mL can of Coke. Thus, it would be roughly 6000 ppm. Atmospheric CO2 ppm is around 400 ppm. Thus, it seem like concentration is what causes it. Maybe it has to do something with the medium. Maybe the CO2 has to be solvated in an aqueous medium for the enzyme to reach it.

Comment: Isn't it a coincidence that the user "Sparkles" is asking about carbonated beverages, one of them being "sparkling water"?